# asserTrue API is not displaying in Robotium

Tags: assert, robotium

I am using Robotium 5.0.1.
assertTure or asserFalse API is not displaying in my eclispe IDE.
How to enable this option?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the code you use? What's the error?

You can write the code belove and report the error (anyway it should work if other robotium methods work):

```
assertTrue(solo.searchText("Pippo"));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually I was solo.assertTure(). Thats why it was displaying "The method assertTrue(boolean) is undefined for the type Solo" error. Could you please explain why solo is not working with assert?

Comment: Because you can use the assert of junit; I think it would be a redundant method. The effect is the same. Please accept my answer if it solved your problem.